# Get Widget Instance in custom function

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to get widget $instance variable values in custom_widget_init function?

```
public function __construct() {
  ....
  add_action( 'wp_head', array( __CLASS__, 'custom_widget_init' ) );           
}

function custom_widget_init() {   

}
```

Comment: why do you need to do this? any specific reason there might be another solution for this

Comment: I need to change the style dynamically.